# Examine PopupRoot in Live Visual Tree viewer for WinUI 3 apps in VS 2022?

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, debugging, winui-3

I use the ***Live Visual Tree*** viewer and ***Live Property Explorer*** tools in *VS 2022* all the time when working with *WinUI 3* apps and *XAML*. Examining, and interacting with, elements in the "regular" visual tree (that starts at `RootScrollViewer`, see attached diagram) is easy but I can't seem to do the same thing with `Popups` and `Flyouts`, which have a different root (`PopupRoot`) than the normal UI tree.

[image: Expanded Live Visual Tree with PopupRoot]

This screenshot shows an expanded `PopupRoot` for a `DatePicker` `Flyout`. But I can't expand any of the `LoopingSelector` elements or look at the ***Live Properties*** for any elements in `PopupRoot` because the `Flyout` closes (and `PopupRoot` becomes empty) as soon as it loses focus.

Is there any way I can examine the `PopupRoot` tree and its element properties in the same, or similar, way I can work with the `RootScrollViewer` tree? Perhaps a setting I've overlooked? Or does anyone know of other tools that would help me achieve this for a *WinUI 3* app?

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Could you please share the code snip of your xaml. I tested DatePicker, but I didn't find any LoopingSelector.

Comment: Certainly and thank you. They're in the `DefaultDatePickerFlyoutPresenterStyle` in the **Generic.xaml** for _WindowsAppSDK v1.2.22116_ which I'll upload when I get to work. To actually see them in the `Visual Tree`, you'll have to copy the `Style` to a test project and load them under a different name (say `CustomDatePickerFlyoutPresenterStyle`). The default style details are normally hidden at that level.

Comment: Please see the additional code below. Thank you.

Comment: I will discuss this with the team.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a custom version of the vanilla `DatePicker` so I can play with `OnApplyTemplate()` and `Measure()`. The `Styles` are right out of the *WindowsAppSDK v1.2.22116* **Generic.xaml** file with modified names (and slight changes to some `Width` properties).

**CustomDatePicker.cs**

```c#
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;

namespace TestDatePicker.Classes;

[ObservableObject]
public partial class CustomDatePicker : DatePicker
{
    [ObservableProperty] private Button _flyoutButton;
    [ObservableProperty] private ColumnDefinition _dayColumn;
    [ObservableProperty] private ColumnDefinition _monthColumn;
    [ObservableProperty] private ColumnDefinition _yearColumn;
    [ObservableProperty] private TextBlock _dayTextBlock;
    [ObservableProperty] private TextBlock _monthTextBlock;
    [ObservableProperty] private TextBlock _yearTextBlock;
    [ObservableProperty] private DatePickerFlyoutPresenter _flyoutPresenter;

    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        FlyoutButton = GetTemplateChild("FlyoutButton") as Button;
        if (FlyoutButton == null) { return; }

        DayColumn = GetTemplateChild("DayColumn") as ColumnDefinition;
        if (DayColumn == null) { return; }
        MonthColumn = GetTemplateChild("MonthColumn") as ColumnDefinition;
        if (MonthColumn == null) { return; }
        YearColumn = GetTemplateChild("YearColumn") as ColumnDefinition;
        if (YearColumn == null) { return; }

        DayTextBlock = GetTemplateChild("DayTextBlock") as TextBlock;
        if (DayTextBlock == null) { return; }
        MonthTextBlock = GetTemplateChild("MonthTextBlock") as TextBlock;
        if (MonthTextBlock == null) { return; }
        YearTextBlock = GetTemplateChild("YearTextBlock") as TextBlock;
        if (YearTextBlock == null) { return; }
    }
}
```

**CustomDatePicker.xaml**
(includes `Styles` for:
`DatePickerBorderThemeThickness`
`CustomDatePickerFlyoutButtonStyle`
`CustomDatePickerStyle`
`DatePickerFlyoutPresenter`
`CustomDatePickerFlyoutPresenterStyle`
`LoopingSelector`
`DefaultLoopingSelectorStyle`
`LoopingSelectorItem`)

```xaml
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:primitives="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives"
    xmlns:helpers="using:TestDatePicker.Helpers">

    <Thickness x:Key="DatePickerBorderThemeThickness">1</Thickness>

    <Style x:Key="CustomDatePickerFlyoutButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="helpers:BindingHelper.StyleLoaded" Value="CustomDatePickerFlyoutButtonStyle"/>
        <Setter Property="ElementSoundMode" Value="FocusOnly" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>

                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups...>

                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" 
                                          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                                          Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" 
                                          BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                          BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                          HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                                          VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                                          AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" 
                                          CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="CustomDatePickerStyle" TargetType="DatePicker" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultDatePickerStyle}">
        <!--<Setter Property="helpers:BindingHelper.StyleLoaded" Value="CustomDatePickerStyle"/>-->
        <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal" />
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource DatePickerButtonBackground}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource DatePickerButtonForeground}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource DatePickerButtonBorderBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource DatePickerBorderThemeThickness}" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{StaticResource UseSystemFocusVisuals}" />
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="-3" />
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="{ThemeResource ControlCornerRadius}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="DatePicker">
                    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">

                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups...>

                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                            Foreground="{ThemeResource DatePickerHeaderForeground}"
                            Margin="{ThemeResource DatePickerTopHeaderMargin}"
                            MaxWidth="{ThemeResource DatePickerThemeMaxWidth}"
                            TextWrapping="Wrap"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                            VerticalAlignment="Top"
                            Visibility="Collapsed"
                            AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />
                        <Button x:Name="FlyoutButton" 
                                Grid.Row="1" 
                                Style="{StaticResource CustomDatePickerFlyoutButtonStyle}" 
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                                Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" 
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                                IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsEnabled}" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                FocusVisualMargin="{TemplateBinding FocusVisualMargin}" 
                                UseSystemFocusVisuals="{TemplateBinding UseSystemFocusVisuals}" 
                                CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}">
                            <!--MinWidth="{StaticResource DatePickerThemeMinWidth}" 
                        MaxWidth="{StaticResource DatePickerThemeMaxWidth}"-->
                            <Grid x:Name="FlyoutButtonContentGrid">

                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" x:Name="DayColumn" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" x:Name="FirstSpacerColumn" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" x:Name="MonthColumn" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" x:Name="SecondSpacerColumn" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" x:Name="YearColumn" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <!-- Code must set the Grid.Column numbers for the TextBoxes based on culture. It also sets the Text. -->
                                <TextBlock x:Name="DayTextBlock" Text="dd"
                                           TextAlignment="Center" 
                                           Padding="{ThemeResource DatePickerHostPadding}" 
                                           FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" 
                                           FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" 
                                           FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" 
                                           AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />
                                <TextBlock x:Name="MonthTextBlock" Text="mm" 
                                           TextAlignment="Center" 
                                           Padding="{ThemeResource DatePickerHostPadding}" 
                                           FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" 
                                           FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" 
                                           FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" 
                                           AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />
                                <TextBlock x:Name="YearTextBlock" Text="yy" 
                                           TextAlignment="Center" 
                                           Padding="{ThemeResource DatePickerHostPadding}" 
                                           FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" 
                                           FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" 
                                           FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" 
                                           AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />
                                <Rectangle x:Name="FirstPickerSpacing" 
                                           Fill="{ThemeResource DatePickerSpacerFill}" 
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                           Width="{ThemeResource DatePickerSpacerThemeWidth}" 
                                           Grid.Column="1" />
                                <Rectangle x:Name="SecondPickerSpacing" 
                                           Fill="{ThemeResource DatePickerSpacerFill}" 
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                           Width="{ThemeResource DatePickerSpacerThemeWidth}" 
                                           Grid.Column="3" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Button>

                    </Grid>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="DatePickerFlyoutPresenter" BasedOn="{StaticResource CustomDatePickerFlyoutPresenterStyle}"/>

    <Style x:Key="CustomDatePickerFlyoutPresenterStyle" TargetType="DatePickerFlyoutPresenter">
        <!--<Setter Property="helpers:BindingHelper.StyleLoaded" Value="CustomDatePickerFlyoutPresenterStyle"/>-->
        <!--<Setter Property="Width" Value="296" />
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="296" />-->
        <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="398" />
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource DatePickerFlyoutPresenterBackground}" />
        <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId" Value="DatePickerFlyoutPresenter" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource DatePickerFlyoutPresenterBorderBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource DateTimeFlyoutBorderThickness}" />
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="{ThemeResource ControlCornerRadius}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="DatePickerFlyoutPresenter">
                    <Border x:Name="Background"
                              Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                              BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                              BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                              CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}"
                              Padding="{ThemeResource DateTimeFlyoutBorderPadding}"
                              MaxHeight="398">
                        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel">

                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid x:Name="PickerHostGrid">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" x:Name="DayColumn" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" x:Name="FirstSpacerColumn" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" x:Name="MonthColumn" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" x:Name="SecondSpacerColumn" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" x:Name="YearColumn" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="FirstPickerSpacing" Fill="{ThemeResource DatePickerFlyoutPresenterSpacerFill}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="{ThemeResource DatePickerSpacerThemeWidth}" Canvas.ZIndex="10000" Grid.Column="1" />
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="SecondPickerSpacing" Fill="{ThemeResource DatePickerFlyoutPresenterSpacerFill}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="{ThemeResource DatePickerSpacerThemeWidth}" Canvas.ZIndex="10000" Grid.Column="3" />
                                    <Grid x:Name="HighlightRect" Canvas.ZIndex="9999" Background="{ThemeResource DatePickerFlyoutPresenterHighlightFill}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="{ThemeResource DatePickerFlyoutPresenterHighlightHeight}" Margin="4,2,4,2" IsHitTestVisible="false" />
                                    <primitives:MonochromaticOverlayPresenter Canvas.ZIndex="10000"
                                              Grid.Column="{Binding ElementName=DayLoopingSelector,Path=(Grid.Column)}"
                                              SourceElement="{Binding ElementName=DayLoopingSelector}" 
                                              ReplacementColor="{ThemeResource DatePickerFlyoutPresenterHighlightForegroundColor}" 
                                              Height="{ThemeResource DatePickerFlyoutPresenterHighlightHeight}" 
                                              VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                              IsHitTestVisible="false" />
                                    <primitives:MonochromaticOverlayPresenter Canvas.ZIndex="10000"
                                              Grid.Column="{Binding ElementName=MonthLoopingSelector,Path=(Grid.Column)}" 
                                              SourceElement="{Binding ElementName=MonthLoopingSelector}" 
                                              ReplacementColor="{ThemeResource DatePickerFlyoutPresenterHighlightForegroundColor}" 
                                              Height="{ThemeResource DatePickerFlyoutPresenterHighlightHeight}" 
                                              VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                              IsHitTestVisible="false" />
                                    <primitives:MonochromaticOverlayPresenter Canvas.ZIndex="10000" 
                                              Grid.Column="{Binding ElementName=YearLoopingSelector,Path=(Grid.Column)}" 
                                              SourceElement="{Binding ElementName=YearLoopingSelector}" 
                                              ReplacementColor="{ThemeResource DatePickerFlyoutPresenterHighlightForegroundColor}" 
                                              Height="{ThemeResource DatePickerFlyoutPresenterHighlightHeight}" 
                                              VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                              IsHitTestVisible="false" />

                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid Grid.Row="1" Height="{ThemeResource DatePickerFlyoutPresenterAcceptDismissHostGridHeight}" x:Name="AcceptDismissHostGrid">

                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Rectangle Height="{ThemeResource DatePickerSpacerThemeWidth}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Fill="{ThemeResource DatePickerFlyoutPresenterSpacerFill}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                                <Button x:Name="AcceptButton" Grid.Column="0" Content="&#xE8FB;" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="{StaticResource DatePickerFlyoutPresenterAcceptMargin}" Padding="4" Style="{StaticResource DateTimePickerFlyoutButtonStyle}" />
                                <Button x:Name="DismissButton" Grid.Column="1" Content="&#xE711;" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="{StaticResource DatePickerFlyoutPresenterDismissMargin}" Padding="4" Style="{StaticResource DateTimePickerFlyoutButtonStyle}" />
                            </Grid>

                        </Grid>
                    </Border>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <!-- Default style for Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.LoopingSelector -->
    <Style TargetType="LoopingSelector" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultLoopingSelectorStyle}" />

    <Style TargetType="LoopingSelector" x:Key="DefaultLoopingSelectorStyle">
        <!--<Setter Property="helpers:BindingHelper.StyleLoaded" Value="DefaultLoopingSelectorStyle"/>-->
        <Setter Property="ShouldLoop" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="{ThemeResource ControlCornerRadius}" />
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{StaticResource UseSystemFocusVisuals}" />
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PrimaryText}" FontFamily="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Control">
                    <Grid>

                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups...>

                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer"
                                VerticalSnapPointsType="Mandatory"
                                VerticalSnapPointsAlignment="Near"
                                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled"
                                ZoomMode="Disabled"
                                Template="{StaticResource ScrollViewerScrollBarlessTemplate}" />
                        <RepeatButton x:Name="UpButton" Content="&#xEDDB;" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" FontSize="8" Height="{ThemeResource LoopingSelectorUpDownButtonHeight}" Padding="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Collapsed" Style="{StaticResource DateTimePickerFlyoutLoopingSelectorNavigationButtonStyle}" Background="{ThemeResource LoopingSelectorUpDownButtonBackground}" Margin="{StaticResource LoopingSelectorUpDownButtonMargin}" IsTabStop="False" />
                        <RepeatButton x:Name="DownButton" Content="&#xEDDC;" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" FontSize="8" Height="{ThemeResource LoopingSelectorUpDownButtonHeight}" Padding="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Visibility="Collapsed" Style="{StaticResource DateTimePickerFlyoutLoopingSelectorNavigationButtonStyle}" Background="{ThemeResource LoopingSelectorUpDownButtonBackground}" Margin="{StaticResource LoopingSelectorUpDownButtonMargin}" IsTabStop="False" />

                    </Grid>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <!-- Default style for Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.LoopingSelectorItem -->
    <Style TargetType="LoopingSelectorItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource LoopingSelectorItemForeground}" />
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="{ThemeResource ControlCornerRadius}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="LoopingSelectorItem">
                    <Grid x:Name="Root" Background="Transparent" Margin="{StaticResource LoopingSelectorItemMargin}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}">

                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups...>

                        <Grid.RenderTransform>
                            <ScaleTransform x:Name="ContentScaleTransform" />
                        </Grid.RenderTransform>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                                Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                Padding="2,0,2,0"
                                Margin="2,0,2,0"
                                HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />

                    </Grid>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

The `LoopingSelector`s themselves are in `CustomDatePickerFlyoutPresenterStyle` (see the `primitives:MonochromaticOverlayPresenter` definitions which reference `DayLoopingSelector`, etc.) but are actually instantiated in `DatePicker` code (which I don't have and can't find).

This **XAML** produces the tree shown in the original question when the `DatePickerFlyout` is open.

Comment: The `helpers:BindingHelper.StyleLoaded` `Setter`s just generate `Trace` messages when `Style`s are actually applied.